# Rails attribute value returned in hexadecimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, associations, wice-grid

I am running the following active record query

`Keyword.joins(:questions, :users, :associations).select("questions.*, keywords.keyword").where(users: {id: @user.id})`

and presenting the results using wice_grid using the following code -

```
<%= grid(@questions, show_filters: :false) do |g|
  g.column name: 'ID', attribute: 'id', filter: false
  g.column name: 'Question', model:'Question', attribute: 'question'
  g.column name: 'Keyword', model:'Keyword', attribute: 'keyword'
end %>
```

The question attribute gets populated fine, but the keyword attribute shows up in hexadecimal value such as #< Keyword:0x00000104eb00a0>. Any idea why? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does `@questions.first.question` return a value you expect?

Comment: @franksort - Yes, it returns the right value. Even `@questions.first.keyword` returns the right value. But surprisingly, it does not do it in wice_grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid#queries-with-join-tables:

> Please note that the blockless definition of the column only works with columns from the main table and it won’t work with columns with :model

```
<%= grid(@questions, show_filters: :false) do |g|
  g.column name: 'ID', attribute: 'id', filter: false
  g.column name: 'Question', model:'Question', attribute: 'question'
  g.column name: 'Keyword', model:'Keyword', attribute: 'keyword' do |question|
    question.keyword.keyword
  end
end %>
```

Comment: it gives the error "undefined local variable or method `questions'"

Comment: @amey1908 I typo'ed.  I meant `question.keyword.keyword`.

Comment: thanks @franksort for pointing to the documentation. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you should be using a <%= instead of a <% tag? That displays the return value of any function, so if grid is returning the keyword object, that would be what is getting displayed.

Comment: I am sure it needs <%= because it needs to print it. Also the documentation on wice_grid says so. :) I agree with you that its returning the keyword object, but I don't understand why is that. If I change the query to `Keyword.joins(:questions, :users).select("questions.*, keywords.keyword").where(users: {id: @user.id})`, it works fine. Not sure why it doesn't work with the query in the original question.